# What do you call the table/counter surrounding a sushi conveyor belt?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm referring to these kind of structures (the part where customers put their plates and eat).

[image]

[image]

At first, I thought about "group tables," but now that I think of it, they could also be called bars? Or maybe there's another more common or accurate term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AmE that is called a **counter**.

> Would you like to sit at a table or at the counter?

The entire assemblage, including the preparation area, is "a sushi bar".

I suppose there may be some speakers who would say:

> I'd like to sit at the bar.

but I've never heard that phrase used in sushi-style restaurants in the US, though it is very common in other kinds of restaurants that serve primarily alcoholic beverages at a bar but also serve food there.